# Angular2/ionic2 angular2-google-maps error Cannot find name 'google'

Tags: google-maps, angular, autocomplete, ionic2, google-places-api

I followed the [this example (click here)](http://brianflove.com/2016/10/18/angular-2-google-maps-places-autocomplete/) to make a field of address with autocompletion of google map Places,

But it's giving the following error:

```
Can not find name 'google'.

L53: this.mapsAPILoader.load (). Then (() => {

L54: let autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete 
(this.searchElementRef.nativeElement, {
```

I tried to install google-maps types `npm install --save @types/google-maps` but it is without results.

After installing @types/google-maps the build is ok but when I luanch i have this error :

[Cannot find name 'google' after installing @types/google-maps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPZzD.png)

My Code :

```js
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Component, ViewChild, OnInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MapsAPILoader } from 'angular2-google-maps/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-page2',
  templateUrl: 'page2.html'
})
export class Page2 implements OnInit {

  latitude: number = 51.678418;
  longitude: number = 7.809007;
  zoom: number = 4;

  searchControl: FormControl;

  @ViewChild("search")
  searchElementRef: ElementRef;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private mapsAPILoader: MapsAPILoader) {
// some not related to this question code
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    //create search FormControl
    this.searchControl = new FormControl();

    //set current position
    this.setCurrentPosition();

    //load Places Autocomplete
    this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
      let autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.searchElementRef.nativeElement, {
        types: ["address"]
      });
      autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", () => {
        //get the place result
        let place: google.maps.places.PlaceResult = autocomplete.getPlace();

        //set latitude and longitude
        this.latitude = place.geometry.location.lat();
        this.longitude = place.geometry.location.lng();
      });
    });
  }

  private setCurrentPosition() {
    if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
        this.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        this.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        this.zoom = 12;
      });
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: what happens when you place `declare var google;` under your `imports` and above your `@Component({})` ? And please provide us with some code

Comment: thanks for your feedback. I've added my code

Comment: could you try `npm install --save @types/google-maps`?

Comment: I've already done that. I get the following error https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPZzD.png

Comment: Ok then try `typings install dt~google.maps --global`

Comment: Yes ! It works with typings install dt~google.maps --global. I thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Cool i'll submit it as an answer so this can be closed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `typings install dt~google.maps --global`

as found [here](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/google-maps-typescript-error-cannot-find-name-google-discussion/49990)

Comment: For me the problem is resolved after the execution of these two instructions which you have given me :
1. npm install --save @types/google-maps
2. typings install dt~google.maps --global


Thank you @Ivaro18